# Debugging network analyst solve error 030024

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, error-030024

I'm trying to build service areas for a low-voltage utility network, but am having trouble solving the network analysis. Here is the code to build the service area:

```py
Treatment_SA = arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaLayer (network, district+"_Treatment_SA", "Length", "TRAVEL_FROM", "200" , "DETAILED_POLYS", "NO_MERGE" , "DISKS", "NO_LINES" , "NON_OVERLAP", "NO_SPLIT", Feeders, "", "", "", "TRIM_POLYS", distance_from_line)
Treatment_SA = Treatment_SA.getOutput(0)


#Load Elements
arcpy.na.AddLocations (Treatment_SA, "Facilities", Injection_TX, "", "25 Meters")
arcpy.na.AddLocations (Treatment_SA, "Polygon Barriers", Existing_TX_Polygons, "", "25 Meters")

#Solve
arcpy.na.Solve(Treatment_SA,"SKIP")
```

I'm not too worried about errors in the code since it has run successfully with other data, but I'm including in this post in case it is helpful. When I run this code, I receive error 030024:

> Solve returned a failure. No edges were traversed. Failed to execute (Solve).

How can I find out more about what is causing this error?

Comment: Is your network built? Is it a network dataset and not a geometric network? (there is a difference) If you do this manually in ArcMap or Pro do you get a result? From the error message *No edges were traversed* either the network is disjoint or your feeders don't match up to edges.

Comment: Can you do the same network analyst solve in ArcMap or Pro, seeing the inputs might help understand why this is happening.

Comment: @MichaeStimson the network is built and it is a network dataset. I tried doing manually in ArcMap and got the same result. Would you mind expanding a bit on what a disjoint network is and what you mean by feeders not matching up to edges? I think the no edges traveresed is the crux of the problem, but unfortunately I'm not finding much relevant info about what that error message means or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever ArcGIS Pro (or ArcMap) returns error messages there is a chance that the error is actually a link to a page like [030024: Solve returned a failure](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/030001-040000/tool-errors-and-warnings-30001-30025-030024.htm):

> **Description**
>
> The Network Analyst solver could not determine a solution.
>
> **Solution**
>
> The solver could fail to compute a solution in many scenarios. Check
>   the messages returned by the solver to figure out the possible reason
>   for the failure. [Learn more about troubleshooting network
>   analyses](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/troubleshooting-network-analyses.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately, the page you linked to only states that the issue I'm experiencing occurs if "there are no traversable edges for any facility", but provides no further explanation on what that means or how to resolve the issue.